# mysql stored value displayed as raw html in vue through php

Tags: php, vue.js

I have a value stored as `<b> supposed to be bold </b>` in mysql.

while fetching through php I used nearly all html entity related functions but no avail

```
//will be returned as json for vue 
  $item ['value'] = $fetched_data;
```

in vue template I use like this

```
{{$value}}
```

and it gives me as html tags where I am supposed to print the bolded text, anything should I do in PHP or Vue to make this happen?

Comment: A good example of where a template system does 'helpful' things at the wrong time.  Escaping the HTML is a feature that can come back and cause problems when you actually don't want it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `v-html="value"` on the element which needs to contain your value.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML